# Query multiple custom post types in single loop

Tags: php, wp-query, loop, query

I'm aware there are several other posts that cover similar ground to what I'm about to ask.

I have three custom post types running, in addition to 'posts'. I want to run a loop that pulls all posts categorised under a particular category

```
 <?php
          $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array ( 
                'taxonomy' => 'testimonial_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'home'
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
                $postcount = 0;
            ?>
            <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $postcount++; ?>
//loop here
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This is the code I have at the moment, not sure how I condense this into pulling in multiply post types from one category.

Answer (score 38):

Just change the `post_type` bit to:

`'post_type' => array('testimonial', 'other_post_type', 'another-post-type'),`

Assuming that taxonomy is valid across all 3 post types. Otherwise you'll have to leave that out.

*Why?* You can pass an array to `post_type` field.

Comment: How do I say what category name to search in.
'taxonomy' => 'testimonial_category'

Comment: @user2478101 : ^^ Your `tax_query` in the question looks OK, though I didn't test it. What are you trying to do differently?

Comment: I have a taxonomy in each post type with a term in called home.I want to pull in any post that has that selected

Comment: I took a gamble and tried this, but it doesn't seem to pull in the other any posts from the custom post types. query_posts( array(
                'post_type' => array('post', 'testimonial', 'casestudy'),
                'cat' => 69,
                'showposts' => 3 ) 
                );

Comment: In order for this to work, the taxonomy must be identical for all. The terms, as far as I know, can't be linked across taxonomies. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12269

Comment: How can I make the taxonomy the same throughout WP?

Comment: register same taxonomy for multiple post types. use same name/slug/etc. "my_one_taxonomy" and then register it for all post types.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => array( 'testimonial', 'post' ),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Edit Note:**
To query for multiple post types you would add an `array()` of post types instead of just querying for one.

Comment: Samundar, can you offer a bit of an explanation for how your answer provides a solution?  Sometimes the users asking a question have already been trying to solve something for hours and just getting a snippet of code can feel daunting.